# Обработка текста ошибки

Tags: golang

У меня есть БД где имена пользователей и email являются уникальными значениями. Если пользователь пытаетсявнести имя пользователя повторно хотелось бы сообщить его об этом.
мой код выглядит таким образом:

```
insert, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SQL"))
if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
}
```

При выполнении условия выдается ошибка

```
Error 1062: Duplicate entry 'sg@e.com' for key 'Email'
2022/05/23 04:54:33 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:49679: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference.....
```

Можно ли как то получить только текст Duplicate entry 'sg@e.com' for key 'Email' ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать обработку ошибки таким образом:

```
insert, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SQL"))
if err != nil {
    if mysqlErr, ok := err.(*mysql.MySQLError); ok && mysqlErr.Number == 1062 {
        fmt.Println(mysqlErr.Message)
    }
}
```

Кастим ошибку к структуре `*mysql.MySQLError`. Если получилось, то выводим только сообщение без номера `mysqlErr.Message`

Проверку номера ошибки можно убрать из `if`. Нужно для того, чтобы добавить кастомный текст ошибки.